# Get dynamically generated list item value

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile

**EDIT/UPDATE:**
OK so I feel a little sheepish now. After nearly two days of circling this issue I find a solution so close to posting.

In a nutshell the click detection `$('#someListView li').click(function() {` needs to be moved OUT of the `pageinit` event and placed INTO the `pagebeforeshow` event after the listitems have been generated. This seems to solve the issue although I must admit I'm not quite sure why....

Also the `.trigger("create")` is not needed. I hope it helps someone.

=====================================================

**ORIGINAL QUERY:**

I have a small issue that I managed to boil down to that below. Basically I want a data value `attr` from a dynamically generated `listview` list item. Sounds simple enough. Hard coding the data works fine and I can access the `data-id` attribute but as soon as I dynamically generate it, the click events appear not to work regardless of refreshing or re-creating parents. The html has been altered as I can see the values when I inspect the elements. Styling appears to be OK.

I have seen many examples on here with re-creating objects and refreshing the list but none seem to work.
If I comment out the `javascript` for generating the list items, the hard-coded items work fine.
I think I am missing something really simple but I can't get my head around what it could be.

html:

```html
<div data-role="page" id="testpage" data-theme="c">
    <div data-role="content" id="testpage_content" data-theme="c">
        <div id="listview_container">
            <ul data-role="listview" id="someListView">
                <li data-id="4444">
                    <a href="#"><p>hard-coded data-id=4444</p></a>
                </li>
                <li data-id="5555">
                    <a href="#"><p>hard-coded data-id=5555</p></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```js
$(document).on('pageinit','#testpage',function(){
    $('#someListView li').click(function() {
        alert($(this).attr('data-id'));
    });
});


$(document).on('pagebeforeshow','#testpage',function(){
    var arrayData = new Array("4444","5555"); //usually generate this data from ajax call
    $("#someListView").empty(); //empty hard-coded list items

    $.each(arrayData, function(key, value){  
        $("#someListView").append(
            '<li data-id="'+ value +'">'+'
            <a href="#"><p>clicking this should alert: '+ value +'</p></a>'+
            '</li>'
        );                          
        $('#someListView').listview('refresh');
    });
    $('#listview_container').trigger('create');
});
```

Comment: change this `$('#someListView li').click(function() {` to this `$(document).on('click', '#someListView li a',function() { alert($(this).attr('href')); });`